# Add key and value to array of objects object from the keys in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
let json = [
  {cat: 'one', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'two', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'three', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'four',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'five',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'six',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'seven',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'eight',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'nine',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  
]
```

I then have an array: `arr = ['device', 'object']`

I have an object:

```
obj= {
  a: 'one',
}
```

I want to add whatever is in the array (in this case `['device', 'object']`) to obj.

In the case above, I want obj to look like these array of objects:

```
[
{
  a: 'one',
  device: 'iphone'
  object: 'google'
},
{
  a: 'two',
  device: 'iphone'
  object: 'bing'
},
{
  a: 'three',
  device: 'iphone'
  object: 'jeeves'
},
.........
]
```

The array of keys (arr) can be different so not sure how to write a reusable function.

Comment: why object is site?

Comment: There isn't enough there to create a relationship between `'object'` and `'site'` programmatically without manually creating that relationship by knowing the actual property names. `'device'` is fine since it exists in the sample data already

Comment: Also, show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right you can do it like this. I assumed that you `json` and `obj` are sorted and have identical listings, otherwise you will also need to make a search by `cat` to find the correct row in `json`

```js
const json = [
  {cat: 'one', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'two', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'three', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
]

const objs = [
  {
    a: 'one',
  },
  {
    a: 'two',
  },
  {
    a: 'three',
  },
]

const arr = ['device', 'site']

const result = objs.map((obj, i) => {
  arr.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = json[i][key]
  })
  
  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```